# Defective Login After Failed Upgrade to macOS Sierra

Tags: terminal, upgrade, macos

Yesterday, I tried to update to the second public beta of macOS Sierra. For some reason, however, the update process stopped shortly before the completion, and since there was no progress even after many hours, I decided to shut down.

Everything works fine as far as the startup is concerned, but I can not login with my regular user account. While the password is recognized as correct, the display turns black when my data are supposed to be loaded, and I am again asked to enter my password.

Neither restarts nor safe boots were of help. I also reinstalled macOS Sierra—probably the first public beta—via the recovery mode completely, but the problem is still there, even in safe mode. Apparently, all of the disk data are still there as well, but I can simply not login due to the black screen.

I tried to create a new admin user via Terminal to check if that account has the same issues. But the problem is that the sudo command, even whereis sudo and which sudo only gives me the line command not found after sudo, whereis and which, respectively.

echo $PATH gives me the response /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. That seems rather long; is it alright?

I would appreciate your help, be it regarding the login issue or enabling the sudo command.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about beta/pre-release software which is outside the scope as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Then feel free to only answer the question regarding the sudo command to create a new user via Terminal, which is not necessarily connected to the beta software.

Comment: @Allan Questions about the public beta are on-topic, see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-10-macos-10-12-watchos-3-or-tvos-10-beta-questions-ok

Comment: @H.Dopp Can you be a bit more specific about the state your system is in: Did you boot into single user mode, from the recovery partition or something else? Which OSX version is running there?

Comment: Currently, I am running the first public beta which I reinstalled via recovery mode in the regular mode. Still, I have the login issues from the second public beta: I can not login with my regular user account. That is why I would like to use Terminal to create a second user to check if that account has the same issues; that, however, is impossible since the sudo command, which is necessary for creating a new user, “is not found”. I suspect that the upgrade to the second public beta caused severe issues, but I am not sure what exactly is wrong in the system.

Comment: What I would appreciate is a way to enable the sudo command in my case. Then, I could hopefully create a new user via Terminal.

Comment: @H.Dopp have you had any luck with it? I'm having the same issue.